# In gRPC unable to bind enum values from message to dontnet core Dto

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, grpc, grpc-web

I need to define a string array type dataType in Grpc message. not sure how to do. right now i am doing it as a

```proto
repeated string Title= 1,
```

here i need name field as string array Type. But it is showing error that it is, field is readonly type when bind data in it:

```cs
public override async Task<UserResponse> CreateUser(
    UserModel request, ServerCallContext context)
{
    var eventResponse = new UserResponse();
    var createCmd = new CreateUserCommand
    {
        Model = new UserDto
        {
            Title = request.Title,
            Id = request.Id,
        }
    }
}
```

here in title i need to bind data

Comment: with the edit: is it `UserModel` or `UserDto` that you're having difficulty with

Comment: the code above I mentioned written in grpc service.and UserDto is from dotnet core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generated code from `protoc` here gives you something like:

```cs
private readonly RepeatedField<string> title_ = new RepeatedField<string>();
[DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute]
public RepeatedField<string> Title {
    get { return title_; }
}
```

So: `Title` is indeed read-only. This means that instead of **assigning** it, you should explore what APIs exist for *adding* to it - i.e.

```cs
var user = new UserDto
{
    Id = request.Id,
}
user.Title.Add(request.Title);
// or AddRange, etc
```

You *may* still be able to use initializer syntax, too:

```cs
new UserDto
{
    Id = request.Id,
    Title = { request.Title }
}
```

(which is an `.Add`)